# Flex : Purepdf : Aligning paragraph text into the middle of a SimpleCell?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I tried with this piece of code, but it doesnt work by some reason..

```
var table : SimpleTable     = new SimpleTable();
    table.widthPercentage   = 100;
    table.borderWidth       = 1;

var row : SimpleCell        = new SimpleCell( SimpleCell.ROW );
    row.border              = 1;
    row.borderColor         = RGBColor.fromARGB( 0x555555 );
    row.borderWidth         = 1;
    row.verticalAlignment   = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

var cell1 : SimpleCell      = new SimpleCell( SimpleCell.CELL );
    cell1.widthpercentage   = 25;
    cell1.verticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

var p : Paragraph = new Paragraph( 'test', PurePDFGenerator.pdf.cyrillicFont );
    p.alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

cell1.add( p );


row.add( cell1 );
table.add( row );
```

- How to align a paragraph text into the middle of a SimpleCell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do horizontal align at the cell level?  From what I can see, it should work from the docs.  Also, are you not adding your paragraph to your cell?

Comment: i am adding it. just missed into copy/paste. sorry about. anyway i think i have tried all possibilieties, and none bringing the text into the middle of the cell.

Comment: That sucks.  Have you tried looking at the [code](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/)?

Comment: it is wried indeed, i have checked so far only a small part of the code. :|

Comment: Well, here's your chance at fixing it and committing it to the project :)

Answer (score 2):

Until Paragraph.alignment works you could use

```
cell.horizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
```